# How to track and terminate processes of a pool based on resource usage?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, resources, threadpool, bioinformatics

I'm working on a Metagenomics pipline,I have a process (Prodigal) that can only take one CPU and I need to run up to 5 at a time. When the "wa of the server gets above 0.3, I need to terminate specific processes from the process pool, or reduce the number of active workers somehow.

After the Prodigal process finishes

A simplified version of the code

```
 def multi_prodigal_processing():
    directories = glob.glob(root)
    prodigal_pool = Pool(processes=5)
    for directory in directories:
        prodigal_pool.apply_async(run_prodigal, (directory,))
```

```
def monitor_prodigal_usage(pool):

     while prodigals_running :
          if check_over_usage() :
              pool.terminate()
```

But this terminates all processes. What I want to do is to terminate the "youngest" process and reduce the pool to three active workers instead. Problem is I only have pool.terminate which will terminate everything, or I could use multiprocessing.active_children() but I think the pool would just keep adding processes even if I stopped them.

Is there any good way of doing this while still using the pool object? Should I just use multiprocess.Process and create a data structure that keeps track of PIDS and using a counting semaphore instead? Wrap the processes and add a halt\start command? there's gotta be an easier way

Comment: How do you define the "youngest" process in a pool; they are all pretty much equivalent? And you can't really just kill a process in a processing pool. Even if you could it might be in the middle of processing one of your directories. The code you posted and your description is "too" simplified for any meaningful answer.

Comment: What I meant is the one that is running the least amount of time. it's fine if I have to kill and it and leave some files in the middle of processing, my concern is not crashing the server. I will consider posting again with a more complex code, thanks for the input.

Comment: I have updated my answer below now terminating the youngest process immediately (and correcting an error).

Comment: @Booboo I've added a working implementation below of your approach would love it if you could take a look to see if I've done it justice, and thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented your approach with some changes, would love it if you could take a look, perhaps there's some flaws I'm overlooking. It's working well and providing consistent expected output. (I'm adding this as answer because of the comment limit)

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager,Queue # Used for multiprocessing prodigal
from queue import Empty
global process_dict  # Keeps track of active prodigal workers
global root_dirs_done  # Keeps track of directories processed with prodigal
global root_dirs_done_iterable  # Multiprocessing object isn't iterable, data is transferred to this after multiprocessing part is over
global directories  # All relevant directories to process from input directory
global root_dirs_queue  # Remaining directories to process
global prodigal_lock  # Synchs access to youngest_process
global youngest_process  # Keeps track of which prodigal input directories is currently being processed,in chronological order
global manager  # Synchs shared resources between prodigal workers

def setup():
    global dir_glob, directories, protein_file, prodigal_lock, root_dirs_done, root_dirs_queue, youngest_process, manager, process_dict, root_dirs_done_iterable
    manager = Manager()
    root_dirs_done_iterable = []
    root_dirs_queue = manager.Queue()
    youngest_process = manager.list()
    root_dirs_done = manager.list()
    prodigal_lock = manager.Lock()
    process_dict = manager.dict()

def prodigal_processing():
    parse_and_place = Process(target=parse_and_place_directories_for_processing)
    parse_and_place.start()
    parse_and_place.join()
    setup_workers(5)
    monitoring = Process(target=monitor_prodigals)
    monitoring.start()  # Monitors the workers until they're all inactive
    monitoring.join()
    post_prodigal_processing() 

def parse_and_place_directories_for_processing():
    global root_dirs_queue
    for directory in directories:  # Parse directories in input directory and 
        if check_directory(directory):   
            root_dirs_queue.put(directory)
def setup_workers(n):
    global process_dict
    for i in range(n):
        p = ProdigalWorker(i)
        process_dict[i] = p
    for p in process_dict.values():
        p.start()

class ProdigalWorker:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.key = i
        self.directory = ""
        self.process = None
        self.work = True

    def start(self):
        self.process = Process(target=self.start_processing)
        self.process.start()

    def start_processing(self):
        global prodigal_lock, youngest_process, root_dirs_done, root_dirs_queue, process_dict
        while self.work:
            if not root_dirs_queue.empty():
                try:
                    self.directory = root_dirs_queue.get_nowait()  # Worker attempts to get a directory from the queue if the queue isn't empty
                    # print("Directory Grabbed by ", self.key)
                    prodigal_lock.acquire()
                    youngest_process.append(self.key)  # Worker updates that they have begun processing
                    prodigal_lock.release()
                    run_prodigal(self.directory)  # Processing begins
                    prodigal_lock.acquire()
                    youngest_process.remove(self.key)  # Signal that they are done to monitor
                    prodigal_lock.release()
                    root_dirs_done.append(self.directory) 
                except Empty:
                    process_dict.pop(self.key)
                    break


            else:
                process_dict.pop(self.key)  # If the queue is empty, process exits and signals to the monitor it isn't processing any more directories
                break

def monitor_prodigals():
    global youngest_process, prodigal_lock, root_dirs_queue
    while True:
        if len(process_dict) == 0:  # Break condition is all workers are done
            break
        if len(process_dict) > 3:  
            if get_wa_usage() > 0.3:  
                prodigal_lock.acquire()
                worker = process_dict.pop(youngest_process.pop())
                worker.work = False
                worker.process.terminate()
                root_dirs_queue.put(worker.directory)
                prodigal_lock.release()
        else:
            for p in process_dict.values():  # If there are equal\less than the minimum, wait for what's running to finish
                try:
                    p.process.join()
                except AttributeError:
                    continue
            if len(process_dict)==0:
                break
            else:
                continue
def main():
    setup()
    prodigal_processing()
```

**Comments by Booboo**

My comments are too long to be actual comments, so pardon my update to your post:

1. In function `prodigal_processing` twice you start a process and then immediately follow that up with a call to `join` for that process. So you are immediately blocking the main process until the newly created subprocess completes. You are therefore not running anything in parallel and there was nothing gained by creating those new subprocesses. You should have just *called* directly `parse_and_place_directories_for_processing` and `monitor_prodigals` for the same but more efficient effect (no overhead of creating new `Process` instances). `post_prodigal_processing` is not defined so I don't know what that is supposed to do and cannot comment on that.
2. In function `setup_workers` you have managed dictionary, `process_dict`, into which you are storing each `ProdigalWorker` instance as a value but the keys you are using are just 0, 1, ... n-1. Surely a list would have made just as much sense and would have been more efficient.
3. Like 99.99% of the people who post questions tagged with `multiprocessing`, you did not also tag the question with the actual platform you are running (Linux? Windows?) on as the SO guidelines request. If you say your code works, then I deduce it must be Linux or some other platform that uses `fork` to create new processes, because you are not explicitly passing the input queue to your new subprocesses but relying on them to be able to access the input queue via global variable `root_dirs_queue`. But on a platform such as Windows this would never work. Each new process would start executing the source from the beginning as part of its initialization with an initially empty address space before method `start_processing` would actually run and consequently only code at global scope would be executed as part of that initialization and `root_dirs_queue` would remain uninitialized. Your code is not wrong, *per se*; it is just very platform-dependent.
4. You are using a managed lock to force the "single threading" of the `append` operation to `youngest_process`. This is totally unnecessary since the `append` operation is thread safe to begin with. Likewise the `remove` operation. Inconsistently, you saw no need to use a lock when appending to `root_dirs_done`. I will have more to say on this later.
5. Managed structures such as the managed queue returned by the call to `manager.Queue` carry a fair amount of overhead. You should use instead `root_dirs_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()`.
6. In `monitor_prodigals`, instead of `if len(process_dict) == 0:` it is more Pythonic to code `if not process_dict:`. This works whether `process_dict` is a `dict` or a `list`. But in the following statement you are testing the length of `process_dict`. So it might be better to just initially assign the length to a variable: `l = len(process_dict); if l == 0: break; if l > 3: etc.`
7. There is something about `monitor_prodigals` and `start_processing` that does not seem quite right. `start_processing` adds itself to the `youngest_process` list when it starts processing a directory and then removes itself when it is through and then goes back looking to see if there is another directory to process. If there isn't, it removes itself from the `process_dict` dictionary (or list). There are processing windows where the number of items in `process_dict` does not equal the number of items in `youngest_process`, i.e. whenever one or more processes have just completed processing a directory and have removed themselves from `youngest_process`. `monitor_prodigals` could test the length of `process_dict` and find that it is greater than 3 but when it goes to pop something from `process_dict` it finds that it is empty. Granted, this is highly unlikely. But it is not so unlikely there might be 4 processes but only now 3 of them in `youngest_process` because one of the processes has just finished processing its directory. What if this was the youngest and it just happened to have finished? You would now be popping the wrong process. Although `append` and `remove` are thread-safe operations and I said you do not need to use a lock individually for these operations, you *do* need to use a lock if you want to combine these operations as a single atomic operation and I think that *is* what you want to do:

```py
def setup_workers(n):
   global process_dict
   for i in range(n):
       p = ProdigalWorker(i)
       process_dict[i] = p
       # Initialize youngest_process:
       youngest_process.append(p.key)
   for p in process_dict.values():
       p.start()

class ProdigalWorker:
    ...
    def start_processing(self):
        global prodigal_lock, youngest_process, root_dirs_done, root_dirs_queue, process_dict
        while True:
            try:
                with prodigal_lock:
                    self.directory = root_dirs_queue.get_nowait()  # Worker attempts to get a directory from the queue if the queue isn't empty
                    youngest_process.remove(self.key)
                    youngest_process.append(self.key)
                run_prodigal(self.directory)  # Processing begins
                root_dirs_done.append(self.directory) 
            except Empty:
                with prodigal_lock:
                    youngest_process.remove(self.key)
                    process_dict.pop(self.key)
                break

def monitor_prodigals():
    global youngest_process, prodigal_lock, root_dirs_queue
    while len(process_dict) > 3:
        if get_wa_usage() > 0.3:
            with prodigal_lock:
                # still > 3?
                if len(process_dict) <= 3:
                    break
                worker = process_dict.pop(youngest_process.pop())
                worker.process.terminate()
                root_dirs_queue.put(worker.directory)
    with prodigal_lock:
        process = [p.process for p in process_dict.values()]
    for p in process:
        p.join()
```

Notice I have removed the unnecessary and *unreliable* check `if not root_dirs_queue.empty():` when using a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance. I am also using the lock as context manager. The result of the changed code is that it appears that I am never removing anything from `youngest_process` but rather just rearranging the order. The number of elements in `youngest_process` will always equal the number of elements in `process_dict`.

**Note** I have made other code changes since quite frankly I made not have understood some of the subtleties of your code. This is true in particular in `monitor_prodigals`. The idea is that when you need to terminate a process because of usage, you are putting the directory back on the queue. The process you have just terminated is dead and the state of its `self.work` flag is irrelevant at this point. As for the other tasks that are still running, you want them to continue to run even if they momentarily find the queue empty if you are in the process of placing back on the queue a directory from a canceled process. But the problem is after the queue gets an empty condition it breaks out of the get loop and could miss the directory being placed back on the queue. If it doesn't break out of the loop and continues to loop as long as `self.work` is True, then it will loop indefinitely.

I would not use `self.work` at all. Instead I am only accessing the input queue using the lock. If a process is terminated because of usage, then the operations of canceling the process and requeuing the directory are also placed under control of the lock.

Now it's *you* who need to review *my* changes carefully.

**Further Update**

I think there is a fundamental flaw in your design. You are adding instances of `ProdigalWorker` to a managed dictionary but after you call method `start_processing` you are initializing an attribute with a `Process` instance thereby indirectly adding a `Process` instance into a managed dictionary. But `Process` instances cannot be shared across address spaces/different processes, so this is an illegal operation. See the following program:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process

def foo(d):
    print(d['x'].p)

class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p = None

def main():
    manager = Manager()
    d = manager.dict()
    x = X()
    d['x'] = x
    print('None' if d['x'].p is None else 'Not None')
    # Now add a Process attribute:
    x.p = Process(target=foo, args=(d,))
    # Still None because the managed dictionary doesn't know of the update:
    print('None' if d['x'].p is None else 'Not None')
    # We must reassign the key to let the dictionary know of the change.
    # But this will now raise an exception:
    d['x'] = x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
None
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Ron\test\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Ron\test\test.py", line 21, in main
    d['x'] = x
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 834, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 347, in __reduce__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons
```

Your code does not throw an exception because even though in method `start` you are setting a `Process` attribute into an object that has been stored into a managed dictionary with ...

```py
    self.process = Process(target=self.start_processing)
```

... the managed dictionary itself has not been updated with the updated object. But this means that when `monitor_prodigals` goes to terminate the youngest worker and executes ...

```py
                worker = process_dict.pop(youngest_process.pop())
                worker.work = False
                worker.process.terminate()
```

... `worker.process` will not have been set and this should throw an exception.

Comment: @Boobo 

Hey, this is in response to your suggestion :)

Comment: Okay, I think my review is complete. I have spent the better part of my life on this.

Comment: And it is incredibly appreciated @Booboo! 

I have read through it but will read through it a couple more times, review your suggestions, try to implement them, and write a succinct response as soon as I can. 

I cannot express my gratitude enough, thanks for your contribution to me, and posterity !

Comment: @Booboo , I've tried to regard all your comments in the most organized way in the following doc

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Nfk3s5sD6X8yx5xchI75BAsTe4mRWcoPuFqOecB--Gs/edit?usp=sharing

Feel free to either comment here or on the doc itself 

Thank you so very much. Unfortunenantly I haven't yet been able to fully test the implementation because even though I've run like 220 prodigal processes at the same time, the wa hasn't gone up beyond 0.1 (which is the minimal value I can test for on my server and with my function).

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea. All the directories are placed on a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance and 5 `Process` instances are created that do non-blocking gets from the queue.

The main process creates a mapping between the subprocess's pid (process id) and the process. This mapping is passed to `monitor_prodigal` which in a loop calls `multiprocess.active_children` to get a list of the currently running subprocesses and prunes the mapping of any entries that represent processes that have terminated. If there are only 3 processes left running (the minimum number), then the processes's completions are simply awaited. Otherwise, your `check_over_usage` function is called and if it returns `True`, then the most recently created process still running is immediately terminated.

The following code provides test functions `run_prodigal`, which just encrypts the passed directory name taking 1 second to do that by sleeping and then outputs the encrypted name along with the current process id and `check_over_usage` that sleeps for 3.2 seconds and returns `True`.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, active_children, current_process
from queue import Empty
import glob

def process_queue(queue):
    while True:
        try:
            directory = queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            # No more directories to process
            break
        else:
            run_prodigal(directory)

def multi_prodigal_processing():
    queue = Queue()
    directories = glob.iglob(root)
    # write directories to queue:
    for directory in directories:
        queue.put(directory)
    process_dict = {}
    for _ in range(5):
        p = Process(target=process_queue, args=(queue,))
        p.start()
        # map process pid to process
        process_dict[p.pid] = p
    print(list(process_dict.keys()))
    monitor_prodigal(process_dict)

def monitor_prodigal(process_dict):
    # While we have active child processes:
    while True:
        s = {child.pid for child in active_children()}
        n_processes = len(s)
        if n_processes == 0:
            # No more child processes
            break
        for pid in list(process_dict.keys()):
            if pid not in s:
                # This process has terminated:
                del process_dict[pid]
        if n_processes > 3:
            if check_over_usage():
                # get process asscociated with the last process created
                # dict since CPython 3.6 maintain insertion order like OrderedDict:
                p = list(process_dict.values())[-1]
                # terminate this process
                p.terminate()
        else:
            # 3 or fewer processes left, just wait for them to finish:
            for p in process_dict.values():
                p.join()
            break

import time
import hashlib
import bcrypt
import base64

root = '/*'

def run_prodigal(directory):
    time.sleep(1)
    directory = directory.encode('utf-8')
    if len(directory) > 72:
        directory = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(directory).digest())
    directory = bcrypt.hashpw(directory, bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('ascii')
    print(current_process().pid, directory, flush=True)

def check_over_usage():
    time.sleep(3.2)
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multi_prodigal_processing()
```

Prints:

```
[20368, 19140, 16780, 13244, 17844]
19140 $2b$12$E.ABtYWNN5NuwnO6iea8yeRG31RKOwAw2ra2S0Hi/erbEFCkl0SNO
20368 $2b$12$VF/gghqaQDmJd/r6URUWHunBFe3yJcJDKml./Vsl.c6apuR8hq9GG
17844 $2b$12$s5QAjdA9w/DLd.0Y9LKaGe8x7IjJ.AKMSPDk6BXGG71OHAJ5gCG.a
13244 $2b$12$2Bkw6GftPbHntNwscBKdsuPSUdbIc3frwPEgaBpW8zTlu1SuCvUsq
16780 $2b$12$QS4pMEHDCewX0PiDrbopiuelYaMXWZ3M0laVL.fK4xdMt5TxSq5qy
20368 $2b$12$WR4U/iBI8LWb8y49Ik9aY.lMnVJGR/e2a3KIxllG2LNkdic9NqyyS
19140 $2b$12$bAspEA3dO9QAewXvH1sZBuhwfoH15PD8W.STAeT2oRwtBvwoodb0G
17844 $2b$12$2/Jj92ynrgODa0Vu7Xg/s.uHnBwXCDu6Dv76qUW1gGrsGzWRGkDS2
13244 $2b$12$goc1WaBcgeuGXimxBaizleE60NS02YRsCyOjHPeBsyaCHSCI1dKGC
16780 $2b$12$1dM/xy3YmlDUtI6AC4FIUuzLP6bwWvltkZ4kEbdieOodwYiK50sM2
20368 $2b$12$JDz4gkW9MKRNrMRBEKYC.O2RJTaWbRctErT7Uc0CaF30NV0PLbcq.
19140 $2b$12$nXZBu1x9Lhu7mzjPYidnveCA.3egA9hChusOic6LuX5r0iDeIkxc.
13244 $2b$12$ySF08jALknQ5lEx0NvCtVe.HOCmLQ/7K/XyBpF6M9iofJkG1iZhx.
16780 $2b$12$sHJ53YxTE1TUKh2y96Ro7uN2GH0JnTxf4Fp1nnzrmKDkq88bDB8G2
19140 $2b$12$hbeZGUPFeY4Zcni9Kl4/ruaUYfXQFZknklwaEvYzUKHpvAZAsi/Wy
20368 $2b$12$OXlxglZu4uxA6crErwHCSOePmCfpmyW.07Ecbd9VsGEoYQYsS0HXC
13244 $2b$12$vVTt4doPee9Rb6zYPwmOvOgD77ci8PvPCS4EciuVi2dKVbn2/Jdzu
16780 $2b$12$ai3VvCzyvfDW2mA.g.zNZeTXKBNn9CAohrP8xaLKFVo1YMUZhH3/C
20368 $2b$12$v7eSFSJVfVHPHhklgDzTCuGYAX9aBZsXjLLLPzQMwc/ZEoIkEDaJ.
19140 $2b$12$ROWRebmd.YK9A32eavzlfu6upXaGgNdZzkryj3X6AGSCEQS5g4lZ6
13244 $2b$12$JXd45AePvcBIZdsqk3kyU.EFrnayKk2Fq/6A95AVPUY5ICZ8j7OVu
16780 $2b$12$fb9GC1Vz0Za22ef3L3nQgesoaOohbuyDchumqfn84l1Qtfv2Q4576
20368 $2b$12$W7EmfaMMu5drZOpBnqrSV.gzWW21XRJh92hCCyO57pPQhRJSp6rQq
19140 $2b$12$h.08rO8Xm8OoWifW3iLMYubatPvddAP5VN7qjl6h3KP3XBBEvSrPu
13244 $2b$12$wTEt00lcPmLDHyFnKnFqZe9ypiIYxisgWcuBwF/cikvN2kxmGSsEO
16780 $2b$12$lWrZGZbnswvjSeOjTPvOK.BrN5qtCUK1fDc2faR86MsJptZz7RBE2
20368 $2b$12$HGf7JYseyxU/IKBR0fH1nO8zR6150bCy.7tlB6qnD7jB2eiqsFWgS
19140 $2b$12$u1ey5KAzAYh/Am.gac1ojemkJxH0r2BXlqZ35776jfBJFnAfoVH06
13244 $2b$12$yfQ6pOn0fS2/P3B8s/wQFele19DCkI6RN.w0Qygf3Mw0ulfrTKLJy
16780 $2b$12$JaBQGu3yv4EmfiiyfdnJwO1lFG1j4wQqHr4tKHCqs53YXJX91QuZq
20368 $2b$12$sOi9X0hO1cvnrGpttpPce.tZBWQJ/SbtSyw28SzaqsGJKyMmGsi0q
19140 $2b$12$FUCaWuGDTDoXn5DUaRTj0.yY1KTlh7Xk25thp.pmtzqyNIbAPwFoW
16780 $2b$12$u04hOYpSdPGJP2dk83FbXOfuok6wENQWaMAtL3vcw09upLSz4hPi2
20368 $2b$12$t4VOitWmywSJYqqpUW0vpObOHv6dBoL59eLnAmqgM88KTdZYkLsEm
19140 $2b$12$KUKWRv.sQsK3/KmbX7JvU.T0VwQQLBlwVbMNGmnSn.I/vsVy1W4yi
16780 $2b$12$JEK8bmWs3TozcENwbJ3CgOCiRkJslMkVW4Imj.NNpVYeewDaewKb.
20368 $2b$12$hYJkV49jHDkmReumkKyyS.BxX7zPk/VS4zQd39qYZGF44q/jitbWW
19140 $2b$12$hX.GTShwYPB4Zd8so8YLKu/nnwVzT59uwUUEMHklBraoW4zF9HAv.
16780 $2b$12$qKjH4L8gulV0CR4eZWwFf.MQnz7iB20Pl7aLqUFh536wtDVaoQVPa
20368 $2b$12$8W/6LA19txF.LdHdTeATKulCHWRS1uF00JgEIlLL3sWb2.H.6sQoS
19140 $2b$12$kVtZqZBcu7/ovSRUhI.aFuv2piiZdIGkPNDmvK.hKj5oVdG7H7DdW
16780 $2b$12$BYzN.2yNN1FqZRsNolpZMu0N/9R7oZvMddJRph5OPozrPAyUWJga6
20368 $2b$12$E5OJLBrPModYAohvlNVc2u6vfQ0584s5ufxdJRa4aIY8w2urak4WK
19140 $2b$12$UOlQ1VZmmGrCV9PJBC/VWO7zimO/BfNqtQuSsnSygKD8EpOah2I8a
16780 $2b$12$3fJXjSsOln228m9CyJ2ZYukghUEdOkeS0irYJSccGrdQfRN6dUVZ.
20368 $2b$12$IiPkrRpJr3Ow18sM70Bu4Os4kcb/FKtijEsljiqc7WZlvgFHqyGF6
19140 $2b$12$oLWYrJaol/GS1cEPmIR37.tmYUEmxgbq/8tbJ5p6blFXUgBzPOUZ2
16780 $2b$12$qZSAZ3O5XCPsUsGCNmsJBOK5792NX2BnuDkP5GOJII8PZbkT46gWi
20368 $2b$12$PXquku9Em/ssrmYzkjlKIey1yxY8Cv9LEA.FuMccxMYOXjPthzS5G
19140 $2b$12$6.68X2mQUrgovkElyAr.8uBQ2NwCmEn5kIVjnIgTjlWAjUnTlm3hO
16780 $2b$12$O6dxFHqQmfR1HcpKCNQsT.jKMdZ0Z6g/xOu.5P.KjjzJAPzOQ5w9y
20368 $2b$12$1Xa2SeTfFpkO41d9iO3GJOWYeiWmq2EduiY7JVPFj5.MgYyCyWqY6
19140 $2b$12$1GgprRojvY28JLnnLPG.0uBrl5FWwS6sLILo.5LJz/F1PYlsL.34.
16780 $2b$12$8hrTBvnSWv959ZTiwu5xE.G70Oi3JTRs03qmRD2b2BEhi6yWwmMFu
20368 $2b$12$X9f45NLv/gz2FH150b2Iaug67bzqYjznGEumHXX4JrLjc6qE1Hi/S
19140 $2b$12$Je0zMSxHn5r7mzYSGHgOBOkFFY7e7SS/BGYm76QhMHWKI6tlZgYj6
16780 $2b$12$2b.WIjEVmOH04lmfLqeBAeU41XtUNMkWe.FAdfPS9IG4Cka30d18S
20368 $2b$12$0LxEkomlpThzXkdcc9f5QO3FXqtXLTRGO2AdWcV6dRSAxF7J.VXn.
19140 $2b$12$Jee.BuEVkkkBzutotKfIW.UYBaHQHu/ftn8u1Svv9cmCFZkOls.wy
```

The five pid's created are in order: 20368, 19140, 16780, 13244, 17844. After 3.2 seconds when `check_over_usage` returns True pid 17844 is terminated and 3.2 seconds after that pid 13244 is terminated. We are then down to 3 processes, the minimum number, so the remaining 3 processes are allowed to run until they are complete.

Comment: Apologies for the intrusion, Can you help me with a [variation of your previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69055834/python-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-after-modifying-code) please

Comment: I've added my implementation below