# Python : IndexError: list index out of range after modifying code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, index-error

My code is supposed to provide output in the below format.

I tried modifying the code and I broke it.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Un-comment next line to supress logging:
        # options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        # print('The driver has been "quitted".')


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def parse_data(url):
    try:
        browser = create_driver()
        browser.get(url)
        df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source)[0]
    except KeyError:
        print('KeyError')
        return None
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id': 'wrap'})
    content = cont.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    content = content.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'}, {'id': 'tournamentTable'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
    if main is None:
        return None
    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[1].text
    league = count[2].text
    game_data = GameData()
    game_date = None
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
            continue
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[1])
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(row[3])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])
        game_data.country.append(country)
        game_data.league.append(league)
    return game_data


# URLs go here
urls = {

    "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/20210903/",

}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = None
    # To limit the number of browsers we will use
    # (set to a large number if you don't want a limit):
    MAX_BROWSERS = 5
    pool = ThreadPool(min(MAX_BROWSERS, len(urls)))
    for game_data in pool.imap(parse_data, urls):
        if game_data is None:
            continue
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

    print(results)
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal
    import gc

    gc.collect()  # a little extra insurance

print(results.head())
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.2\scratches\scratch_13.py", line 107, in <module>
    for game_data in pool.imap(parse_data, urls):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 870, in next
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.2\scratches\scratch_13.py", line 72, in parse_data
    league = count[2].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The results are usually in the follow format:

```
     date   time                          game score home_odds draw_odds away_odds   country          league
    0          None  15:30       Wolves - Manchester Utd   0:1   393/100     69/25     39/50   England  Premier League
    1          None  13:00               Burnley - Leeds   1:1   231/100     64/25   123/100   England  Premier League
    2          None  13:00           Tottenham - Watford   1:0     23/50     87/25   709/100   England  Premier League
    3   28 Aug 2021  16:30           Liverpool - Chelsea   1:1     29/20     59/25   207/100   England  Premier League
    4   28 Aug 2021  14:00       Aston Villa - Brentford   1:1   109/100     58/25     74/25   England  Premier League
    5   28 Aug 2021  14:00            Brighton - Everton   0:2     33/25    113/50   239/100   England  Premier League
    6   28 Aug 2
021  14:00       Newcastle - Southampton   2:2     73/50   257/100   189/100   England  Premier League
```

How can i get the data?

verbose:

I have a code that runs url cyclically for the next matches  and I want to modify it . the Xpath for the matches 'next matches' for oddsportal is: //*[@id="col-content"]/div[3]/div/div/span
This image. [image: I want this code to run through all these pages and get the concat dataframe value]

Please help

Comment: @booboo I am trying to emulate the [behaviour of this code](https://pastebin.com/46ZmEMaA) to your sulution that has been so very useful.

Comment: you cannot create a new question every time you think we don't answer quickly enough for you

Comment: Agreed however this is another solution/problem

Comment: if you have four different indexerrors in your code to scrape the same site you clearly need more personal study on the subject before asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only date I see is at the top of the page with the caption "Next Soccer Matches:".

I don't see any point in your initial creation of a dataframe with `df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source)[0]` and your subsequent iteration of that dataframe; you should just be iterating directly the  tags of the main table. Done correctly you will end up with the correct values in the country and league columns.

I have also changed a few names of variables to more closely reflect what type of value they hold. Also, I have simplified a bit your navigation through the HTML hierarchy recognizing that a element with an id attribute must be unique within the document so you can directly retrieve it by that id and do not have to first retrieve its parent.

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import re

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Un-comment next line to supress logging:
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        # print('The driver has been "quitted".')


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []

def generate_matches(table):
    tr_tags = table.findAll('tr')
    for tr_tag in tr_tags:
        if 'class' not in tr_tag.attrs:
            continue
        tr_class = tr_tag['class']
        if 'dark' in tr_class:
            th_tag = tr_tag.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
            a_tags = th_tag.findAll('a')
            country = a_tags[0].text
            league = a_tags[1].text
        elif 'deactivate' in tr_class:
            td_tags = tr_tag.findAll('td')
            yield td_tags[0].text, td_tags[1].text, td_tags[2].text, td_tags[3].text, \
            td_tags[4].text, td_tags[5].text, country, league

def parse_data(url):
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    table = div.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'})
    h1 = soup.find('h1').text
    m = re.search(r'\d+ \w+ \d{4}$', h1)
    game_date = m[0]
    game_data = GameData()
    for row in generate_matches(table):
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[0])
        game_data.game.append(row[1])
        game_data.score.append(row[2])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[3])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.country.append(row[6])
        game_data.league.append(row[7])
    return game_data


# URLs go here
urls = {

    "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/20210903/",

}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = None
    # To limit the number of browsers we will use
    # (set to a large number if you don't want a limit):
    MAX_BROWSERS = 5
    pool = ThreadPool(min(MAX_BROWSERS, len(urls)))
    for game_data in pool.imap(parse_data, urls):
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

    print(results)
    #print(results.head())
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal
    import gc
    gc.collect()  # a little extra insurance
```

Prints:

```
            date   time                                         game score home_odds draw_odds away_odds     country            league
0    03 Sep 2021  00:00                      Petrolera - Dep. Pasto    2:3      -128      +245      +334    Colombia     Copa Colombia
1    03 Sep 2021  00:00                       Jalapa - Export Sebaco   0:2      -137      +266      +307   Nicaragua      Liga Primera
2    03 Sep 2021  00:00                        Venezuela - Argentina   1:3      +799      +376      -270       World    World Cup 2022
3    03 Sep 2021  00:05                            Canada - Honduras   1:1      -196      +290      +597       World    World Cup 2022
4    03 Sep 2021  01:00                               Peru - Uruguay   1:1      +231      +204      +140       World    World Cup 2022
..           ...    ...                                          ...   ...       ...       ...       ...         ...               ...
219  03 Sep 2021  23:00                   Greenville - Toronto FC II   3:0      -147      +263      +363         USA    USL League One
220  03 Sep 2021  23:30                 Nashville SC - New York City   3:1      +166      +235      +166         USA               MLS
221  03 Sep 2021  23:30  Philadelphia Union - New England Revolution   0:1      +164      +256      +154         USA               MLS
222  03 Sep 2021  23:30                   Louisville City - FC Tulsa   0:1      -233      +394      +459         USA  USL Championship
223  03 Sep 2021  23:30                    Tampa Bay - Oakland Roots   3:0      -227      +320      +573         USA  USL Championship

[224 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: How would I get the date column to reflect date of the event?

Comment: Thanks! However, this is not exactly the end solution I am looking for. I have [this code that cycles through](https://pastebin.com/73sXCQRq) all the [next matches listed on the landing page](https://imgur.com/a/GUI5m1G) and provides an output which is similar to your output [date resolved to this dataframe format](https://gofile.io/d/arEqxI). If you can help me get there. I will do all that I should. Thank you so much!). If you can help me get there. I will do all that I should. Thank you so much!

Comment: [This is my full explanation](https://pastebin.com/YDnpUVrQ)

Comment: I have updated the answer. By the way, your links to pastebin.com do not show anything.

Comment: (Stackoverflow has a character limit and hence this platform.)
[I have this code ](https://pastebin.com/73sXCQRq) as my end product
 
[It scrapes this dataframe ](https://gofile.io/d/arEqxI)
 
Your code is headless and I would like to use it. However, I am not a coder. I can get only so far lol. [So, I would really like your code to scrape this dataframe](https://imgur.com/a/GUI5m1G). It can because the page(s) is(are) the same. (https://imgur.com/a/GUI5m1G)
 
Please let me know how I can help you.

-Pastebin dump

Comment: I don't know what you mean that the code is "headless". And the dataframe you created and iterate with `itertuples` is *not* usable because the first row of data  of the HTML table when read as a  dataframe is being interpreted as the column names and you are therefore not iterating that first row.  That's why I used a different approach. Are you saying that the output I created is not what you want? It has the columns your output showed with what appears to me to be the correct data.

Comment: No no. The output is **exactly** as I had imagined. This is great! Your approach is the best I have come accorss and I am going to adopt this. Thank you again!
What I am saying is thet there are [8 pages whose data I need to scrape in the same fashion](https://imgur.com/a/GUI5m1G) as https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/ How can I dynamically move between pages using your code?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "move between pages." You can certainly put in variable `urls` multiple days worth of URLs and get a dataframe with lots of days. If you are looking to do something different from the current question, you *must* post a new question after you have *accepted* this answer if your question as posted has been answered. Piggy-backing new questions in comments like this should not be done on this forum.

Comment: I should add, however, that SO is not a coding service. You need to make an initial attempt at solving the problem yourself and only if you are stuck wit a particular issue should you post a question.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you!

Comment: [Asked a new question as suggested.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095530/iterate-over-urls-for-webscraping-using-beautifulsoup)