# Iterate over URLS for Webscraping using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my code to scrape odds from [www.oddsportal.com](http://www.oddsportal.com).

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import os
import re

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Un-comment next line to supress logging:
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        # print('The driver has been "quitted".')


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def generate_matches(table):
    global country, league
    tr_tags = table.findAll('tr')
    for tr_tag in tr_tags:
        if 'class' not in tr_tag.attrs:
            continue
        tr_class = tr_tag['class']
        if 'dark' in tr_class:
            th_tag = tr_tag.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
            a_tags = th_tag.findAll('a')
            country = a_tags[0].text
            league = a_tags[1].text
        elif 'deactivate' in tr_class:
            td_tags = tr_tag.findAll('td')
            yield td_tags[0].text, td_tags[1].text, td_tags[2].text, td_tags[3].text, \
                  td_tags[4].text, td_tags[5].text, country, league


def parse_data(url):
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    table = div.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'})
    h1 = soup.find('h1').text
    m = re.search(r'\d+ \w+ \d{4}$', h1)
    game_date = m[0]
    game_data = GameData()
    for row in generate_matches(table):
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[0])
        game_data.game.append(row[1])
        game_data.score.append(row[2])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[3])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.country.append(row[6])
        game_data.league.append(row[7])
    return game_data


# URLs go here
urls = {

    "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/20210903/",

}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = None
    # To limit the number of browsers we will use
    # (set to a large number if you don't want a limit):
    MAX_BROWSERS = 5
    pool = ThreadPool(min(MAX_BROWSERS, len(urls)))
    for game_data in pool.imap(parse_data, urls):
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

    print(results)
    # print(results.head())
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal
    import gc

    gc.collect()  # a little extra insurance
```

Currently, the code just gets data for one urls. I would like
I am trying to integrate this part into my code that allows the pages to be iterated over all the links for "Yesterday, today, tomorrow and the next 5 days" as below:

[image: These links]

This part of another code allows to get the URLs.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
def get_urls(browser, landing_page):
    browser.get(landing_page)
    urls = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in
            browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                '.next-games-date > a:nth-child(1), .next-games-date > a:nth-child(n+3)')]

    return urls
....

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_url = "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/"
    urls = []
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    results = None
    urls = get_urls(browser, start_url)
    urls.insert(0, start_url)

    for number, url in enumerate(urls):
        if number > 0:
            browser.get(url)
        html = browser.page_source
        game_data = parse_data(html)

        if game_data is None:
            continue

        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
```

How do I get the `urls` to integrate with my code and iterate to provide me with one single dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make some adjustments to function `generate_matches` since the returning of certain class names was not reliable. And I removed global statements from that function that I never have never should have had.

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import os
import re

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Un-comment next line to supress logging:
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        # print('The driver has been "quitted".')

threadLocal = threading.local()

def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver

class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []

def generate_matches(table):
    tr_tags = table.findAll('tr')
    for tr_tag in tr_tags:
        if 'class' in tr_tag.attrs and 'dark' in tr_tag['class']:
            th_tag = tr_tag.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
            a_tags = th_tag.findAll('a')
            country = a_tags[0].text
            league = a_tags[1].text
        else:
            td_tags = tr_tag.findAll('td')
            yield td_tags[0].text, td_tags[1].text, td_tags[2].text, td_tags[3].text, \
                  td_tags[4].text, td_tags[5].text, country, league

def parse_data(url, return_urls=False):
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    table = div.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'})
    h1 = soup.find('h1').text
    m = re.search(r'\d+ \w+ \d{4}$', h1)
    game_date = m[0]
    game_data = GameData()
    for row in generate_matches(table):
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[0])
        game_data.game.append(row[1])
        game_data.score.append(row[2])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[3])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.country.append(row[6])
        game_data.league.append(row[7])

    if return_urls:
        span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'next-games-date'})
        a_tags = span.findAll('a')
        urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com' + a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags]
        return game_data, urls
    return game_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = None
    pool = ThreadPool(5) # We will be getting, however, 7 URLs
    # Get today's data and the Urls for the other days:
    game_data_today, urls = pool.apply(parse_data, args=('https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer', True))
    urls.pop(1) # Remove url for today: We already have the data for that
    game_data_results = pool.imap(parse_data, urls)
    for i in range(8):
        game_data = game_data_today if i == 1 else next(game_data_results)
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

    print(results)
    # print(results.head())
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal
    import gc

    gc.collect()  # a little extra insurance
```

Prints:

```
             date   time                                 game score home_odds draw_odds away_odds     country            league
0     07 Sep 2021  00:00             Pachuca W - Monterrey W    0:1      +219      +280      -106      Mexico     Liga MX Women
1     07 Sep 2021  01:05              Millonarios - Patriotas   1:0      -303      +380      +807    Colombia         Primera A
2     07 Sep 2021  02:00        Club Tijuana W - Club Leon W    4:0      -149      +293      +311      Mexico     Liga MX Women
3     07 Sep 2021  08:30         Suzhou Dongwu - Nanjing City   0:0      +165      +190      +177       China        Jia League
4     07 Sep 2021  08:45       Kuching City FC - Sarawak Utd.   1:0      +309      +271      -143    Malaysia    Premier League
...           ...    ...                                  ...   ...       ...       ...       ...         ...               ...
1305  14 Sep 2021  21:45       Central Cordoba - Atl. Tucuman  +192      +217      +146        13   Argentina  Liga Profesional
1306  14 Sep 2021  22:00                  Colo Colo - Everton  -141      +249      +395        11       Chile  Primera Division
1307  14 Sep 2021  23:30   Columbus Crew - New York Red Bulls     -         -         -         1         USA               MLS
1308  14 Sep 2021  23:30            New York City - FC Dallas     -         -         -         1         USA               MLS
1309  14 Sep 2021  23:30             Toronto FC - Inter Miami     -         -         -         1         USA               MLS

[1310 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `Traceback (most recent call last): ...... Exception ignored in: <function Driver.__del__ at 0x000001A806AF3E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.2\scratches\scratch_15.py", line 26, in __del__
AttributeError: 'Driver' object has no attribute 'driver'` Is it because of my browser version?

Comment: [Traceback full error](https://pastebin.com/Q1qTMNEZ)

Comment: I had that problem, too. You need to update your chromedriver to match your new Chrome version (93?)

Comment: Yep, did that and now this error: `Traceback (most recent call last): .....
     File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.2\scratches\scratch_15.py", line 76, in parse_data
    game_date = m[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Is the code not picking any values at `m = re.search(r'\d+ \w+ \d{4}$', h1)` ?

Comment: A couple of points: First, there is no line  76 in function `parse_data` in the source I posted above. Are you running with the same exact code I posted or have you modified the code (it sounds like the latter), because the code I posted clearly worked for me. Second, we had agreed that *you* were supposed to make an initial attempt at solving this but you didn't. Against my better judgement I spent time on this anyway.

Comment: Following the line `h1 = soup.find('h1').text` add `print(h1)` to see what the actual text is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236902/discussion-between-pynoob-n-and-booboo).

Comment: When there are no scores i.e. when the matches are not yet started, The score column gets populated with odds values i.e. `game_data.score.append(row[2])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[3])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[5])` shifts when there are no matches played and thus provides incorrect output. Can you tweak it such that if there is no `score` value, it should return `NaN` else `score` ? . [Please find my output](https://gofile.io/d/Nv4wgQ)

Comment: Should I open a new question for the same? Though seems an overkill, you are the best one to guide here

Comment: When there is a score for an event, `table-score` is populated and when no score for the event, the row `table-score` is absent. How can I accomodate for the same in your code? [Please find explanation](https://imgur.com/a/nOnc7Yi)

Comment: [Asked a new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69119519/beautifulsoup-when-row-not-present-nan-else-value)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to integrate this method when iterating over urls.

Code snippet-

```
#assuming you have a list of start_urls
start_urls=['https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/20210903/']

urls=[]

#get links for Yesterday, today, tomorrow and the next 5 days
for start_url in start_urls:
    driver.get(start_url)
    html_source=driver.page_source
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html_source,'lxml')
    dates=soup.find('span',class_='next-games-date')
    links=dates.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        urls.append(('https://www.oddsportal.com'+link['href']))

#get data from each link
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    #function call to parse data

    #function call to append data
```

Comment: Where in my code would I be integrating this part?

Comment: I believe the respondent is suggesting that you just hardcode the list of 8 dates in `urls`. But, of course, this is what I believe the whole question was trying to avoid so that you can run the program on *any* arbitrary day without having to update the code every time. The code also does not seem to be using the multithreading code that is available in the OP's code.

Comment: @PyNoob_N This was just a suggestion, to tell where exactly this should go in, I'd like to know more about the whole process.

Comment: The whole process is that this code should scrape all the values in the dataframe for all the matches for the given days on the website i.e. url = https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer On any given dat there are listings for 8 days of matches. The aim is to get that data in entirety.