# Beautifulsoup: When row not present, NaN else value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code gets data from [www.oddsportal.com](http://www.oddsportal.com)

How can I accomodate for when there is no score present for any event in this code?

Currently, the code scrapes all data from the pages:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import os
import re

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Un-comment next line to supress logging:
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        # print('The driver has been "quitted".')


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def generate_matches(table):
    tr_tags = table.findAll('tr')
    for tr_tag in tr_tags:
        if 'class' in tr_tag.attrs and 'dark' in tr_tag['class']:
            th_tag = tr_tag.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
            a_tags = th_tag.findAll('a')
            country = a_tags[0].text
            league = a_tags[1].text
        else:
            td_tags = tr_tag.findAll('td')
            yield td_tags[0].text, td_tags[1].text, td_tags[2].text, td_tags[3].text, \
                  td_tags[4].text, td_tags[5].text, country, league


def parse_data(url, return_urls=False):
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    table = div.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'})
    h1 = soup.find('h1').text
    print(h1)
    m = re.search(r'\d+ \w+ \d{4}$', h1)
    game_date = m[0]
    game_data = GameData()
    for row in generate_matches(table):
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[0])
        game_data.game.append(row[1])
        game_data.score.append(row[2])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[3])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.country.append(row[6])
        game_data.league.append(row[7])

    if return_urls:
        span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'next-games-date'})
        a_tags = span.findAll('a')
        urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com' + a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags]
        return game_data, urls
    return game_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = None
    pool = ThreadPool(5)  # We will be getting, however, 7 URLs
    # Get today's data and the Urls for the other days:
    game_data_today, urls = pool.apply(parse_data, args=('https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer', True))
    urls.pop(1)  # Remove url for today: We already have the data for that
    game_data_results = pool.imap(parse_data, urls)
    for i in range(8):
        game_data = game_data_today if i == 1 else next(game_data_results)
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

    print(results)
    # print(results.head())
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal
    import gc

    gc.collect()  # a little extra insurance
```

[image: When scores are present, table-score is populated]

When scores are present, `table-score` is populated

[image: When scores are not present, table-score is not present]

When scores are not present, `table-score` is not present

Right now, the column values for `home_odds`, `away_odds` and `draw_odds` shift when `table-score` is not present and hence, providing data incorrectly.

How can I change

```
    game_data.score.append(row[2])
    game_data.home_odds.append(row[3])
    game_data.draw_odds.append(row[4])
    game_data.away_odds.append(row[5])
```

such that if `table-score` is not present, `game_data.score.append(row[2])` would return `NaN` and

```
game_data.home_odds.append(row[2])
game_data.draw_odds.append(row[3])
game_data.away_odds.append(row[4])
```

else as the output is currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first:

```py
from numpy import nan
```

And then modify code as follows:

```py
        ...
        # Score present?
        if ':' not in row[2]:
            # No, shift a few columns right:
            row[5], row[4], row[3], row[2] = row[4], row[3], row[2], nan
        game_data.score.append(row[2])
        game_data.home_odds.append(nan if row[3] == '-' else row[3])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(nan if row[4] == '-' else row[4])
        game_data.away_odds.append(nan if row[5] == '-' else row[5])
        ...
```

Note that `generate_matches` has to be modified to return `list` instances rather than `tuple` instances since the above code now requires that the return values, i.e. `row`, be modifiable.

Putting it all together:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool, Pool
from functools import partial
import os
import re

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Un-comment next line to supress logging:
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        # print('The driver has been "quitted".')


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def generate_matches(table):
    tr_tags = table.findAll('tr')
    for tr_tag in tr_tags:
        if 'class' in tr_tag.attrs and 'dark' in tr_tag['class']:
            th_tag = tr_tag.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
            a_tags = th_tag.findAll('a')
            country = a_tags[0].text
            league = a_tags[1].text
        else:
            td_tags = tr_tag.findAll('td')
            yield [td_tags[0].text, td_tags[1].text, td_tags[2].text, td_tags[3].text, \
                  td_tags[4].text, td_tags[5].text, country, league]


def parse_data(process_pool, url, return_urls=False):
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    # Wait for initial content to be dynamically updated with scores:
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    table = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-matches"]/table')
    # If you do not pass a Pool instance to this function to use
    # multiprocessing for the more CPU-intensive work,
    # then just replace next statement with: return process_page(browser.page_source, return_urls)
    return process_pool.apply(process_page, args=(browser.page_source, return_urls))

def process_page(page_source, return_urls):
    soup = bs(page_source, "lxml")
    div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'table-matches'})
    table = div.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'})
    h1 = soup.find('h1').text
    print(h1)
    m = re.search(r'\d+ \w+ \d{4}$', h1)
    game_date = m[0]
    game_data = GameData()
    for row in generate_matches(table):
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[0])
        game_data.game.append(row[1])
        # Score present?
        if ':' not in row[2]:
            # No, shift a few columns right:
            row[5], row[4], row[3], row[2] = row[4], row[3], row[2], nan
        game_data.score.append(row[2])
        game_data.home_odds.append(nan if row[3] == '-' else row[3])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(nan if row[4] == '-' else row[4])
        game_data.away_odds.append(nan if row[5] == '-' else row[5])
        game_data.country.append(row[6])
        game_data.league.append(row[7])

    if return_urls:
        span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'next-games-date'})
        a_tags = span.findAll('a')
        urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com' + a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags]
        return game_data, urls
    return game_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = None

    pool = ThreadPool(3) # This seems to be optimal for this application
    # Create multiprocessing pool to do the CPU-intensive processing:
    process_pool = Pool(min(5, os.cpu_count())) # 5 seems to be optimal for this application
    # Get today's data and the Urls for the other days:
    game_data_today, urls = pool.apply(parse_data, args=(process_pool, 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer', True))
    urls.pop(1)  # Remove url for today: We already have the data for that
    game_data_results = pool.imap(partial(parse_data, process_pool), urls)
    for i in range(8):
        game_data = game_data_today if i == 1 else next(game_data_results)
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

    print(results)
    # print(results.head())
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal
```

Prints:

```
Next Soccer Matches: Today, 10 Sep 2021
Next Soccer Matches: Tuesday, 14 Sep 2021
Next Soccer Matches: Wednesday, 15 Sep 2021
Next Soccer Matches: Thursday, 16 Sep 2021
Next Soccer Matches: Yesterday, 09 Sep 2021
Next Soccer Matches: Sunday, 12 Sep 2021
Next Soccer Matches: Monday, 13 Sep 2021
Next Soccer Matches: Tomorrow, 11 Sep 2021
             date   time                              game     score home_odds draw_odds away_odds     country                league
0     09 Sep 2021  00:00            Cumbaya - Guayaquil SC       1:0      -169      +263      +462     Ecuador               Serie B
1     09 Sep 2021  00:00            FC Tulsa - Indy Eleven       2:1      -104      +265      +237         USA      USL Championship
2     09 Sep 2021  00:05           Pumas Tabasco - Atlante       0:2      +221      +186      +134      Mexico  Liga de Expansion MX
3     09 Sep 2021  00:05                   Panama - Mexico       1:1      +518      +250      -156       World        World Cup 2022
4     09 Sep 2021  00:10        Defensa y Justicia - Tigre  0:1 pen.      +138      +199      +214   Argentina        Copa Argentina
...           ...    ...                               ...       ...       ...       ...       ...         ...                   ...
1987  16 Sep 2021  19:00      Olympiacos Piraeus - Antwerp       NaN      -137      +296      +371      Europe         Europa League
1988  16 Sep 2021  19:15               Academica - Estrela       NaN      -106      +231      +290    Portugal       Liga Portugal 2
1989  16 Sep 2021  21:00               Barnechea - Rangers       NaN      +202      +202      +127       Chile             Primera B
1990  16 Sep 2021  22:00  San Marcos de Arica - S. Morning       NaN      +212      +214      +122       Chile             Primera B
1991  16 Sep 2021  23:30       U. De Concepcion - Coquimbo       NaN      +158      +198      +162       Chile             Primera B

[1992 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: So i tested the code, I am getting these values picked randomly which are wrong  Shouldnt the code be `game_data.score.append(nan if row[2] == '-' else row[2])
        game_data.home_odds.append(nan if row[3] == '-' else row[2])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(nan if row[4] == '-' else row[3])
        game_data.away_odds.append(nan if row[5] == '-' else row[4])`  ?

Comment: I don't understand the point you are making with the image you are referencing nor do I understand why you would be setting  the `home_odds` values to either `nan` or `row[2]` based upon what is in `row[3]` when `row[2]` happens to be the same value you are assigning to the `score` values and you never set any `home_odds` values to `row[3]` with your suggested code. But if *you* think your code makes sense then go with you think is correct.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that when there are scores, there are 6 rows of data and when there are no scores, there are 5 rows of data. I gess your part accomodates for if there is no data or "-" for every row correctly. I am unsure how I can accomodate if there is just 1 row i.e. `table-score` is missing. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can I change row index if the outer HTML `<td class="center bold table-odds table-score">1:0</td>1` is not present? How? I guess that might be one way to go. How is where I am requesting your help. Thanks!

Comment: Can we approach it like if the row index <6, then Score is NaN else your code? How do i script this logic?

Comment: See the updated code. Perhaps it's correct now.

Comment: Added one more refinement.

Comment: Yes, This is perfect! Also, can you guide me to where I can upgrade myself on Webscraping principles and techniques? I think that might come handy for me.

Comment: Web scraping is a *very* large topic. Sometimes all the data is to be found in the initial page load, which can be retrieved using, for example, the [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) from the PyPi repository with BeautifulSoup (no need to use Selenium). But more often it's only after the initial page is loaded that the content is dynamically updated with JavaScript and that requires the use of Selenium. In fact, I have updated the source again. (more...)

Comment: See 2 statements following comment *# Wait for initial content to be dynamically updated with scores:*. This ensures that we are waiting long enough (up to 5 seconds) for the content to be updated by testing for the presence of the score tables. And note that Selenium has its own API for retrieving elements. So when you have complicated interactions that require navigation between pages, you really need to study Selenium. You actually do not even need BeautifulSoup; you can use `lxml` directly.  BeautifulSoup does not support XPATH but Selenium and `lxml` do. So study those.

Comment: Fortunately, the content was being dynamically updated very quickly so that even without explicitly waiting for the presence of the score table, by time the code looked for the table, it had already been loaded. But the additional two lines of code just added is *much* better.

Comment: I have updated the code yet again to speed it up a bit: (1) I have reduced the thread pool size to 3 (2) I have removed the code to invoke garbage collection at the end of the program as it is really not necessary to quit the drivers; deleting `threadlocal` is sufficient and (3) Separating out from `parse_data` the CPU-intensive BeautifulSoup code for which using a multiprocessing pool to perform the processing saves a little bit of time. It's not a great savings in this case but it's a useful technique to know and demonstrates how to use both a threadpool and a multiprocessing pool together.