# Python Selenium Web Scraping with Same URL but Multiple Instances (Multiprocessing?)

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing

Running a python selenium script using ChromeDriver that goes to one (and only one) URL, enters data into the form then scrapes the results. Would like to do this in parallel by entering different data into the same URL's form and getting the different results.

In researching Multiprocessing or Multithreading I have found Multithreading is best for I/O bound tasks and Multiprocessing best for CPU bound tasks.

Overall amount of data I'm **scraping** is small, select text only so don't believe I/O bound? Does this sound correct? From what I've gathered is that in general web **scrapers** are I/O intensive, maybe my example scenario is just an exception?

Running my current (sequential, non parallel) script, Resource Monitor shows chrome instance CPU usage ramp up AND across all (4) cores. So is chrome using multiprocessing by default and the advantage of multiprocessing within python really in being able to apply the scripts function to each chrome instance? Maybe I got this all wrong...

Also is it that a script that wants to open multiple URL's at once and interact with them inherently CPU bound due to that fact that it runs a lot of chrome instances? Assuming data scraped is small. Ignoring headless for now.

Image attached of CPU usage, spike in the middle (across all 4 CPU's) is when chrome is launched. [image: CPU Usage]

Any comments or advice appreciated, including any pseudo code on how you might implement something like this. Didn't share base code, question more around the structure of all this.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69119519/beautifulsoup-when-row-not-present-nan-else-value/69119745#69119745). A thread pool is used for starting chromedriver instances using a special technique so that only one chromedriver is ever started per pool process regardless of how many URLs are eventually scraped. Note the final `delete threadlocal` statement at the end of the program required to ensure that all the chromedriver instances are "quitted" when the program terminates. (more...)

Comment: Although it probably does not save that much total elapsed time, the processing of a URL in this example can be neatly divided into the retrieval of a URL and waiting for a table to appear and the subsequent, more CPU-intensive processing of that table using BeautifulSoup. For the latter processing a multiprocessing pool is used.